# Facebook SDK Causes Warning in app Gradle File (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the following dependency

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
```

Where the `${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}` part refers to the value "25.3.1". Now the issue is that Gradle says that there is a conflict due to the existence of multiple versions of the same support library (specifically 25.0.0 and 25.3.1). I run the Gradle dependency tree task and viewed it. I finally found the conflict and it's caused by the Facebook SDK which uses the following:

```
com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0
com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0@aar
```

How to solve this conflict? I know the app is working and everything but a crash may happen in runtime. I also want to get rid of the warning in the Gradle file.

Comment: which version you are using for your dependencies?

Comment: As mentioned in the question: Where the ${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion} part refers to the value "25.3.1"

Comment: Try 25.0.0 and facebook sdk com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0 this works for me